# Setting up a Web server in CentOS

Tags: webserver, centos

Hey guys I'm having a big problem. I've been trying to set up my web server in CentOS. I successfully set up LAMP already but my friends can't access it. How do I fix that? And how do I set up a domain name in Apache? I tried changing the ServerAddress to like *www.example.com* but when I typed in my server address in Chrome, it says www.example.com could not be found. What could be the problem? Please, help me.

Comment: Is your domain name registered?  Does it point to the Internet-facing static address given by your Internet provider?  Look here: [What's a Domain Name Registrar?](http://www.kaneworks.com/what%E2%80%99s-a-domain-name-registrar-and-what%E2%80%99s-an-isp/)

Comment: Where are you running your server? Does your machine has a Public IP ? if not do you have your friends in the same network ?

Comment: paulsm4: Haven't registered my domain yet but thanks for reminding :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DNS

Setting the ServerName in apache doesn't affect other computers.  Your computer has an IP address. DNS is how a name like example.com gets translated to an IP address.

For the time being try to use your IP address in the browser.  You can find your ip address by using the `ifconfig` command.  Then prefix your IP address with http:// in your browser.

If you don't have a public IP address (behind a router, etc), only people on your network can access it.
http://192.168.X.X is a private IP address, there are a few others

A quick way to fake DNS is to use the "hosts" file.

If all of that is set up and it still doesn't work, check the firewall...

### Firewall

Try disabling the firewall to test access.

```
service iptables stop && sleep 60 && service iptables start
```

This will take down your firewall for 1m.  If that's the issue, then open a hole in your firewall for port 80 and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want a ServerName directive. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Second, DNS has to resolve that server name to an IP that correctly routes to the machine running Apache.